# Защита от XSS, простая задача

Tags: javascript

Здрасте, вот есть такое задание, уже пол ночи сижу, не могу понять как это сделать, просто еще не проходили этот материал, но задание уже дали. Помогите пожалуйста.

Ваша задача: обезопасить свою страницу от внедрения вредоносного кода с помощью функции валидации testUserText
функция должна вывести на страницу текст пользователя безопасным способом
т.е. текст должен быть выведен "as is" ( как есть ), но код не должен быть выполнен

```
function testUserText ( userText ) {
      return userText
}
function insertUserText ( userText ) {
      var x = document.createElement ( 'div' )
      x.innerHTML = testUserText ( userText )
      document.body.appendChild ( x )
}

insertUserText (`<svg/onload='document.write("Looser");
                  document.body.style.backgroundColor="black";
                  document.body.style.color="red";
                  document.body.style.fontSize="50px";
                  document.body.style.fontWeight="bold";
                  document.body.style.textAlign="center";
                  document.body.style.paddingTop="45%";'>`)
```

Comment: Потому что это 2 занятие по JS, и это одно из домашних заданий, и я предположил что на 2 занятии не будет ничего сложного и решение элементарно, просто я его не знаю.

Comment: Используйте innerText вместо innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Вот таким будет ответ на мой вопрос, разобрали этот момент на занятии.

```
function testUserText ( userText ) {
      return userText.split("<").join("&lt;")
}
function insertUserText ( userText ) {
      var x = document.createElement ( 'div' )
      x.innerHTML = testUserText ( userText )
      document.body.appendChild ( x )
}

insertUserText (`<svg/onload='document.write("Looser");
                  document.body.style.backgroundColor="black";
                  document.body.style.color="red";
                  document.body.style.fontSize="50px";
                  document.body.style.fontWeight="bold";
                  document.body.style.textAlign="center";
                  document.body.style.paddingTop="45%";'>`)
```

Comment: Замены только < недостаточно - https://stackoverflow.com/q/22799576/1988244

Comment: Разработан кем? Учителем? Если да, смело ставьте 1 с жирным минусом. Используйте просто как и сказали вам выше `innerText` и забудете о головных болях. Либо юзайте АЛЯ `htmlspecialchars` - аналог `php`.